# A conjecture regarding the integral of the square of an entire function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration

Can some help me prove or disprove the following assertion which I encountered in research? Thanks!

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be an analytic function. If for $\forall c > 0$, we can find some $t'>0$ such that

$$\int_{t'}^{t' + 1} {{f^2}(\tau )d\tau }  \le c $$
then
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to \infty } f(t) = 0.$$

Comment: What about the function $f(t) = (\sin^2(t) + e^{-t})^t?$

Comment: This is good, but how do we know that it is analytic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's false.  Take for example 
$$ 
f(x) =\sum_{n\in {\Bbb Z}} e^{-n(x-n)^2}. 
$$ 
Clearly $f(n) \ge 1$ for all integers $n$.  Since in intervals of length $1$ the function $f$ is large only in a small neighborhood of an integer, it is easy to see that $\int_x^{x+1} f(t)^2 dt$ tends to zero as $|x| \to \infty$.

Comment: This is a brilliant counter-example, thanks!